# Summation indices for Bonferroni's inequality

Tags: probability-theory

I'm supposed to prove one of Bonferroni's inequalities:

$$P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k\right) \le\ \sum_{k=1}^nP(A_k) -  \sum_{i < j} P(A_i\cap\ A_j) + \sum_{i<j<k}P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k).$$

But I'm a bit confused about the summation indices when it has $i<j<k$: what does this actually mean? Does it mean a triple summation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just means the summation over all triples $(i,j,k)$ such that $1\leqslant i<j<k\leqslant n$. For example, if $n=5$, then the possible values for $(i,j,k)$ are $$(1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,2,5),(1,3,4),(1,3,5),(1,4,5),(2,3,4),(2,3,5),(2,4,5),(3,4,5).$$

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, sometimes mathematicians write
$$
\sum_{i<j}
$$
when they mean
$$
\sum_{i\,:\,i<j}
$$
(so that $i$ is a bound variable and $j$ is a free variable, so the value of the whole expression depends on the value of $j$) and sometimes they use the **same** notation when they mean
$$
\sum_{i,j\,:\,i<j}
$$
(so that both variables are bound) and they simply rely on context to indicate which is meant.

However, in Bonferroni's inequality, the latter meaning is intended, as is the following:
$$
\sum_{i,j,k\,:\,i<j<k}
$$